# Obfuscate android asset files

Tags: android, encryption, assets

I would like to do some basic obfuscation of files in my assets folder.

I realize that this would only slow down a dedicated reverse engineer, but I'm mostly hoping just to deter casual extraction of some of our assets.

The files are in plain text, so I thought BASE64 might make sense, however it would be trivial for anyone to write a BASE64 decoder as far as I can see, so an added level of entropy seems to be called for.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could encrypt your files with a secret key (that is hard-coded in your app).
Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952618/java-string-encrypt#15954508) for simple encrypt/decrypt routines

Answer (score 0):

As of now the best way to protect the assets folder is to encode it and decode it at run time and you can manage the keys in your java code. No other way is fool proof.