# Libgdx: Obfuscate game assets

Tags: java, android, encryption, libgdx

i am trying to find a way to obfuscate my libgdx assets.
I would like to do it with a private key phrase.

Dont know how can I make this work with the [AssetManager](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/AssetManager.html) class.

The way a load my files is:

```
dynamicManager = new AssetManager();
game.dynamicManager.load("loadingscreen/loadingscreen0.jpg", Texture.class);
    game.dynamicManager.load("sounds/levelup.ogg", Sound.class);
    game.dynamicManager.load("sounds/bow.ogg", Sound.class);
```

I have found a way to ecrypt/decrpyt a string:

[Java string encrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952618/java-string-encrypt#15954508)

But need some help on obfuscating on a libgdx game asset folder.
Has anyone achieved such a thing? Please Help!

Comment: Why do you want to use private key cryptography?

Comment: well, i am open to any ideas. I thought it was a good way: 1) encrypt assets with an algorithm and a key 2)decrypt the assets when reading them using libgdx.
What do you think is best?

Comment: Where would you store that key? Hardcode it?

Comment: Not private key crypto.  You should use symmetric encryption.  Another thing to keep in mind is that if the encryption and decryption take place on the same device then the assets arent really protected.  The decryption key can be retrieved from the application.

Comment: I was planning on storing the key in the application code but splitted in different parts an re assemble the key when decrypting.
What do you think? Have you experience?

Comment: It is very easy to decompile a jar and get your source code. If someone really wants your assets they will get them. You can obfuscate your code and your assets and use all the encryption you want, but in the end you just create a lot of work for yourself. Who are you afraid will steal your assets and what do you think they will do with them?

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to obfuscate or protect your assets. None of them will really stop anyone determined to get your assets. If the game contains the assets AND the key to unlocking them, then they are not really protected. It just takes a little more work to extract.

Lets say you encrypt your assets with a private key as you suggest. No one will be able to read you files. So far so good. The problem comes when you store the key to decrypt the files in your source. Your jar can be easily decompiled and the source is right there just as you wrote it.

You can try to discourage casual hacking/stealing of your assets by going through a lot of hoops and loops, but in the end is it really the casual hackers you should worry about?
I found a link with some ideas for some minimal effort ideas to discourage the casual hackers: [scirra.com](https://www.scirra.com/tutorials/39/how-to-secure-your-game-assets)

If you worry about some Chinese clone dev stealing your game, then sometimes all they do is change the package name in the code and sell is as their own.
This is what copyrights and trademarks are for.

Comment: Hello IronMoney, thanks for your answer. I see what you mean, however there a lot of casual crackers that simple enter the .apk and steal the asset folder, and that is the majority I must say. 

My objective is to make it harder for them and discourage them.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: do you know what I mean?